# Can I combine groupby data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns home and away. So one row will be England vs Brazil and the next row will be Brazil England. How can I count occurrences of when Brazil faces England or England vs Brazil in one count?

Based on previous solutions, I have tried

```
results.groupby(["home_team", "away_team"]).size()
results.groupby(["away_team", "home_team"]).size()
```

however this does not give me the outcome that I am looking for.

Undesired output:
home_team    away_team
England  Brazil       1

away_team    home_team
Brazil  England       1

I would like to see:
England Brazil 2

Comment: Please post what you want to see, as well as what you are seeing.

Comment: Undesired output:
home_team    away_team   
England  Brazil       1

away_team    home_team   
Brazil  England       1

I would like to see:
England Brazil 2

Comment: @jiggy357, you can checkout my answer. also, post your expected output back to the question with formatting, so that everyone can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort values by [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html), create `DataFrame` and use your original solution:

```
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['home','away']], axis=1), columns=['home','away'])
        .groupby(["home", "away"])
        .size())
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you need  below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'home':['England', 'Brazil', 'Spain'],
    'away':['Brazil', 'England', 'Germany']
})

pd.Series('-'.join(sorted(tup)) for tup in zip(df['home'], df['away'])).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Brazil-England    2
Germany-Spain     1
dtype: int64
```

PS: If you do not like the `-` between team names, you can use:

```
pd.Series(' '.join(sorted(tup)) for tup in zip(df['home'], df['away'])).value_counts()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.
Thanks for the help

Comment: @jiggy357, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

You can use `numpy.sort` to sort the values of the dataframe
However, as that sorts in place, maybe it is better to create a copy of the dataframe.

```
dfTeams = pd.DataFrame(data=df.values.copy(), columns=['team1','team2'])
dfTeams.values.sort()
```

(I changed the column names, because with the sorting you are changing their meaning)

After having done this, you can use your `groupby`.

```
results.groupby(['team1', 'team2']).size()
```

**Option 2**

Since a more general title for your question would be something like *how can I count combination of values in multiple columns on a dataframe, independently of their order*, you could use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html).

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.

More precisely, create a `Series` of frozen sets, and then count values.

```
pd.Series(map(lambda home, away: frozenset({home, away}), 
              df['home'], 
              df['away'])).value_counts()
```

Note: I use the dataframe in @Harv Ipan's answer.